# How to use !function () to access JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html

How do I use `!function ()` externally using the JavaScript developer console?

For example:

```
!function (){ 
    function setScore(){
        alert("I need to access this using javascript");
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear....  Are you asking how can you call setScore? Or are you actually asking how to run that code in the console? Aka, copy, paste, execute?

Answer (score 1):

You use it the same way you use it in a script.

The `!function` creates a local scope, so `setScore` is not visible outside the function. You need to call the function (so it's an IIFE), and then call `setScore()` within it.

```js
!function() {
  function setScore() {
    alert("I need to access this using javascript");
  }
  setScore();
}();
```

If you want to call `setScore()` from outside, you need to assign it to a global variable.

```js
!function() {
  setScore() {
    alert("I need to access this using javascript");
  }
  window.setScore = setScore;
}();
setScore();
```

Comment: Alright Thanks alot i wont be able to do it with out help

Comment: What more help do you need? Just paste this into the console and it should work.